after 24.04 upgrade, unable to connect vpn l2tp
I did upgrade my ubuntu and did some apt upgrade... I tried the vpn and it was not working anymore.
This is a previously working L2TP network connection integrated with Duo(2fa).
The request is sent to Duo in my mobile device, so the password is ok, the connection is drop regardless if I accept it in Duo or not. I asked for help on the corp but even the vpn support was unable to figure out why it is failing.
While digging in logs I found this:
2024-06-25T06:09:41.675046-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10817]: connection '15189f67-8fc3-479f-986a-4d15fd469d6a' established successfully                                                                                                                                                  
2024-06-25T06:09:41.767567-03:00 ca372nt nm-l2tp-service[10569]: strongSwan IPsec connection is up.                                                                                                                                                                                         
2024-06-25T06:09:41.768124-03:00 ca372nt nm-l2tp-service[10569]: kl2tpd started with pid 10823                                                                                                                                                                                              
2024-06-25T06:09:41.771622-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=info tunnel_name=t1 session_name=s1 message="new dynamic session" session_id=15762 peer_session_id=0 pseudowire=7                                                                                                     
2024-06-25T06:09:41.771709-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=info tunnel_name=t1 message="new dynamic tunnel" version=2 encap=UDP local= peer=(ip removed):1701 tunnel_id=58408 peer_tunnel_id=0                                                                                  
2024-06-25T06:09:41.771734-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 message="fsm event" event=open                                                                                                                                                                   
2024-06-25T06:09:41.771777-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=send message_type=avpMsgTypeSccrq                                                                                                                                     
2024-06-25T06:09:41.771796-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=send message_type=avpMsgTypeSccrq ns=0 nr=0 isRetransmit=false                                                                                                        
2024-06-25T06:09:41.808385-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="socket recv" length=147                                                                                                                                              
2024-06-25T06:09:41.808563-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=recv message_type=avpMsgTypeSccrp                                                                                                                                     
2024-06-25T06:09:41.808614-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="send complete" message_type=avpMsgTypeSccrq error=null                                                                                                               
2024-06-25T06:09:41.808663-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 message="fsm event" event=sccrp                                                                                                                                                                  
2024-06-25T06:09:41.808709-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=send message_type=avpMsgTypeScccn                                                                                                                                     
2024-06-25T06:09:41.808807-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=send message_type=avpMsgTypeScccn ns=1 nr=1 isRetransmit=false                                                                                                        
2024-06-25T06:09:41.991015-03:00 ca372nt snap-store[3115]: fwupd_client_download_bytes_async: assertion 'url != NULL' failed                                                                                                                                                                
2024-06-25T06:09:42.363906-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="socket recv" length=12                                                                                                                                               
2024-06-25T06:09:42.364059-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="send complete" message_type=avpMsgTypeScccn error=null
2024-06-25T06:09:42.364100-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=info tunnel_name=t1 message="control plane established"
2024-06-25T06:09:42.364205-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=info tunnel_name=t1 message="data plane established"
2024-06-25T06:09:42.364267-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 message="fsm event" event=newsession
2024-06-25T06:09:42.364320-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 session_name=s1 message="fsm event" event=tunnelopen
2024-06-25T06:09:42.364418-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=send message_type=avpMsgTypeIcrq
2024-06-25T06:09:42.364473-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=send message_type=avpMsgTypeIcrq ns=2 nr=1 isRetransmit=false
2024-06-25T06:09:42.401192-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="socket recv" length=28
2024-06-25T06:09:42.401332-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=recv message_type=avpMsgTypeIcrp
2024-06-25T06:09:42.401384-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 message="fsm event" event=sessionmsg
2024-06-25T06:09:42.401471-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="send complete" message_type=avpMsgTypeIcrq error=null
2024-06-25T06:09:42.401519-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 session_name=s1 message="fsm event" event=icrp
2024-06-25T06:09:42.401565-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=send message_type=avpMsgTypeIccn
2024-06-25T06:09:42.401611-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=send message_type=avpMsgTypeIccn ns=3 nr=2 isRetransmit=false
2024-06-25T06:09:42.440646-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="socket recv" length=34
2024-06-25T06:09:42.440759-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=error tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="frame receive failed" error="malformed header: length 58408 exceeds buffer bounds of 30"
2024-06-25T06:09:43.161581-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="socket recv" length=12
2024-06-25T06:09:43.161667-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="send complete" message_type=avpMsgTypeIccn error=null
2024-06-25T06:09:43.161695-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=info tunnel_name=t1 session_name=s1 message="control plane established"
2024-06-25T06:09:43.161745-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=info tunnel_name=t1 session_name=s1 message="data plane established"
2024-06-25T06:09:43.161817-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=info message="session up" tunnel_name=t1 session_name=s1 tunnel_id=58408 session_id=15762 peer_tunnel_id=28458 peer_session_id=372
2024-06-25T06:09:43.167292-03:00 ca372nt pppd[10843]: Plugin pppol2tp.so loaded.
2024-06-25T06:09:43.169053-03:00 ca372nt pppd[10843]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.9/nm-l2tp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
2024-06-25T06:09:43.171954-03:00 ca372nt pppd[10843]: pppd 2.4.9 started by root, uid 0
2024-06-25T06:09:43.172573-03:00 ca372nt pppd[10843]: Using interface ppp0
2024-06-25T06:09:43.172679-03:00 ca372nt pppd[10843]: Connect: ppp0 <-->
2024-06-25T06:09:43.172775-03:00 ca372nt pppd[10843]: Overriding mtu 1500 to 1400
2024-06-25T06:09:43.172969-03:00 ca372nt pppd[10843]: Overriding mru 1500 to mtu value 1400
...
2024-06-25T06:09:43.174990-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[1092]: <info>  [1719306583.1745] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
2024-06-25T06:09:45.553622-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="socket recv" length=36
2024-06-25T06:09:45.553780-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=recv message_type=avpMsgTypeSli
2024-06-25T06:09:45.553874-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=error tunnel_name=t1 message="bad control message" message_type=avpMsgTypeSli error="no specification for v2 message avpMsgTypeSli"
2024-06-25T06:09:45.553919-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 message="fsm event" event=close
2024-06-25T06:09:45.553960-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=send message_type=avpMsgTypeStopccn
2024-06-25T06:09:45.554000-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=send message_type=avpMsgTypeStopccn ns=4 nr=3 isRetransmit=false
2024-06-25T06:09:45.588828-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="socket recv" length=36
2024-06-25T06:09:45.588978-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message=recv message_type=avpMsgTypeCdn
2024-06-25T06:09:45.589041-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=debug tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="send complete" message_type=avpMsgTypeStopccn error=null
2024-06-25T06:09:45.602530-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=info message="session down" result= tunnel_name=t1 session_name=s1 tunnel_id=58408 session_id=15762 peer_tunnel_id=28458 peer_session_id=372
2024-06-25T06:09:45.602626-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=info message="killing pseudowire"
2024-06-25T06:09:45.602676-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=info tunnel_name=t1 session_name=s1 message=close
2024-06-25T06:09:45.602743-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=error tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="socket read failed" error="use of closed file"
2024-06-25T06:09:45.602808-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=error tunnel_name=t1 function=transport message="transport down" error="transport shut down by user"
2024-06-25T06:09:45.602847-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=info tunnel_name=t1 message=close
2024-06-25T06:09:45.602884-03:00 ca372nt NetworkManager[10823]: level=error tunnel_name=t1 message="unhandled v2 control message" message_type=avpMsgTypeSli
2024-06-25T06:09:45.603416-03:00 ca372nt pppd[10843]: Terminating on signal 2

I found strange that no /dev/pts is set on Connect: ppp0 <-->. But I can not figure out why.
Any tips on how to troubleshoot or fix it?

The following steps helped me to fix the issue with l2tp vpn connection failure "AL31L NetworkManager[24377]: level=error message="pppd exited with an error code" error="exit status 16" error_message="the link was terminated by the modem hanging up""
sudo apt install xl2tpd
sudo apt purge go-l2tp

Regarding the following go-l2tp kl2tpd error:
NetworkManager[10823]: level=error tunnel_name=t1 message="bad control message" message_type=avpMsgTypeSli error="no specification for v2 message avpMsgTypeSli"

See the following bug reports:

https://github.com/katalix/go-l2tp/issues/6
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/golang-github-katalix-go-l2tp/+bug/2068687

Your workplace has a router or other device running OpenL2TP which has triggered a bug with kl2tpd. You didn't encounter the issue with older Ubuntu releases as they were using xl2tpd.
A workaround is to use the following network-manager-l2tp PPA which has a newer go-l2tp-0.1.8-1 package that has the bug fix:

https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp

